# how to catch the sys.exit value in one program from other program in python

Tags: python, subprocess, exit-code

I have one python file a.py. I am returning from the file using `sys.exit(some_val)`.

Now, I have one more file b.py, from which I am executing a.py like below:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE, shell = True)
output, error = proc.communicate()
```

Can you please let me know if there is any way to get the value (which is returned by using `sys.exit()` from a.py) from b.py?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `proc.returncode`:

```
print "a.py exited with code {0}".format(proc.returncode)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the return code from `proc.returncode`, but calling a python program from another python program via subprocess seems a stange thing to do...

Comment: Yes. But there are some 100 test case files. Instead of running every script manually, I wrote one script which will run all the test cases present one by one. For that I used subprocess.

Comment: @kadina: you could use `nose`, `py.test`, `unittest` to discover and run tests.